# Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 won't boot (failed to connect to lvmetad, hard drive not detected)

Tags: boot, hard-drive, dell

This problem has been troubling me for a while, and it also appears to be a very popular question. However, despite my best efforts, I can't get any of the suggestions I've found to work.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a Dell XPS 13 2-in-1, and occasionally, maybe every few weeks or months, it just won't start up. When I got the machine, it had Windows installed, and I wiped everything to install Ubuntu. Here's the general timeline of what happens.

First, I'll see some error that complains of a read-only file system. For instance, last night, I was running a program that runs a bunch of Python scripts, and it gets halfway through, and just starts throwing errors because the files are supposedly read only. Another time, I could not even change directories in a terminal because it says “cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system.”

Second, it goes to a black screen and says "WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning." I have to restart manually at this point.

Third, it won't boot. On startup, it emits super loud single beep noise, and it complains that the hard drive isn't detected. See attached image.

[image]

In the past, I've fixed this temporarily by restarting about twenty times, and eventually, it has always gone back to normal. However, I'd like to take care of it for good.

Edit:

Here's another message I got when it failed back to a black screen: "nvme nvme0: failed to set APST feature (-19)". It paused for a few minutes, and then I get "EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_find_entry:1436:inode #4064582: comm gdm3: reading directory lblock 0"

Comment: sounds like it may be a hardware problem ... especially if you have replaced harddrive, ram or SSD ... if yes I would remove then re-seat whichever you have replaced in the past ... just a wild guess

Comment: @ScottStensland I have never replaced any of the parts before

Comment: if its still under warranty then I'd call Dell otherwise I suggest you identify whether it will take a SSD ... update your question with exact model number and possibly someone can tell you whether it can handle a SSD ... read this link https://www.dell.com/support/contents/us/en/04/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/locate-service-tag/notebook   on laptop bottom flip up that plate in middle to reveal your Dell Service Tag ... then look it up at https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04?app=products&~ck=mn   to see which SSD it needs and just buy one and install it - good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking it was an Ubuntu bug that was fixed. Years later, I'm now running 22.04 on the same device without any problems and without ever having made any adjustments to the physical device.